# What do the different colors of the tab title in iTerm2 mean?

Tags: iterm

While using iTerm2, I have noticed that sometimes the color of the title of a tab changes to pink with a loading indicator or changes to red. What do these things mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The iTerm **color change** of Tab labels **indicates activity**.

It can be turned of in:
Preferences > Appearance > Color tab labels on activity

The help file explains this "Color tab labels on activity" appearance preference as follows:

> If selected, tab labels become purple when a non-selected tab has new
>   output, and red when a non-selected tab has output you haven't seen
>   but that is not very recent.

Comment: Is there some way to configure what it considers "output"? I have tabs that turn colors all the time when there are no apparent changes in output.  This makes it useful, for example, to watch for changes in a chat in another tab.